# Delete points on one side of a line in QGIS

Tags: qgis, line, delete, point

I have a bunch of points and line that represents a boarderline as shown below:

[image]

I want to delete all the points one the right side of the line, and letting the points in the left side stay. I dont know how to do that without being a polygon with closed paths. I have tried to use spatial query, but its only working with polygons as far as I know.
What can I do?

Comment: There's probably a complicated way to do exactly what you're asking for, but wouldn't it be easier to just convert the border line into a polygon?

Answer (score 5):

You could run a single sided buffer on the line, with a sufficiently large buffer size to cover all the points to the right. This will get you a nice polygon covering the points you want to delete, which you could then use with the "Select by Location" algorithm to select the intersecting points. Then delete the selected points.